# Why do I not receive an "i" variable back?

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm trying to make a function that will increment the `i` value by one every 2 seconds and then use that function in my `main()` to display the correlating `i` value in `array[]`. I'm not seeing the behavior I thought I would be seeing, does anyone know why I'm not able to see the array value? I've added print statements to confirm that I am incrementing properly and they look to be doing just that. I just can't get it to execute in the `main()`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 3
#define var1 0x1000
#define var2 0x0100
#define var3 0x0200
#define var4 0x0300

int i_num(int i)
{
    while(i<3)
    {
        if(i<2)
        {
            sleep(2);
            i++;
            //printf("This is the new value of array: %d\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            sleep(2);
            i = 0;
            //printf("This is back to the original value of array: %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{

unsigned int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {var1|var2, var1|var3, var1|var4};

printf("This is the value of array[0]: %d\n", array[i_num(0)]);

}
```

Comment: Try stepping through `i_num` mentally, keeping track of the value of `i`.  If it's passed a value less than 3, it never returns.

Comment: The while-loop never ends as it cycles through 0-1-2-0-1-2...

Comment: Your `i_num` function never exits the `while` loop because it keeps resetting `i` to zero, and it never prints anything because the `printf` calls are commented out, so your program never prints anything. You do not show an example of what output you expect or an example of what output you observe, so merely stating “I'm not seeing the behavior I thought I would be seeing” is not helpful. Edit the question to provide a proper [mre].

Comment: I feel like you may have some deeper confusion about how functions work.  A line like 
`printf("This is the value of array[0]: %d\n", array[i_num(0)]);` will call `i_num` one time with argument 0; then when `i_num` returns, its return value will be used to index into `array`, and the corresponding value from `array` will be printed.  But executing this `printf` once will never print multiple lines; it won't re-run the print as `i_num` modifies its argument internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the new value of array:

You do not change the value of the array defined in the `main` function only the local variable `i` in your function. I would abstract from your example as it has not too much sense.

1. Modifying the variable in the calling function. You need to use reference (pointer to it)

```
void foo(int *i)
{
    (*i)++;
    printf("*i in foo = %d\n", *i);
}

int main(void)
{
    int p = 4;

    foo(&p);
    printf("p in main = %d\n", p);
}
```

result:

```
*i in foo = 5
p in main = 5
```

But if you do not pass the reference, you will modify the local variable:

```
void foo(int i)
{
    (i)++;
    printf("i in foo = %d\n", i);
}

int main(void)
{
    int p = 4;

    foo(p);
    printf("p in main = %d\n", p);
}
```

result:

```
i in foo = 5
p in main = 4
```

Comment: Just to note, this is correct but it wasn't the problem in the question. The code in the question would actually return a different value of `i` even if there are no pointers involved. The main problem was the infinite `while` loop since `i` was set to `0` every time before exiting it

Comment: Thank you this gives me a better understanding as to where my issue is stemming from